# Is there a max limit of ibdata files I can add to innodb?

Tags: mysql, innodb, linux

As the title suggests I was supposed to add an additional ibdata file for our mysql archive server since it was near full. Its an old server and I just stumbled on it today. As I checked it, the my.cnf contents of the server is not using an autoextend config on its data file. It has a 320 ibdatas and I only managed to add 2 ibdata from 320 t0 322 because I encountered an error.

The innodb_data_file_path config is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umFED.png) and below is the error If I try to add additional ibdata(i.e. ibdata323:8G)

```
220605 08:16:33 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
220605 08:17:52 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
220605  8:17:53 [ERROR] InnoDB: syntax error in innodb_data_file_path
220605  8:17:53 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
220605  8:17:53 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
220605  8:17:53 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: unknown option '--a323:8G'
220605  8:17:53 [ERROR] Aborting

220605  8:17:53 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

I'm wondering why it prompted me with that kind of error. I double checked if I'm doing any typo which is impossible since its only separated by semicolon. I tried using other filename but same error occur. So I'm guessing is there any max limit on the number of ibdata file we can add. I'm only able to add about 16gb of storage and it will last for 2 weeks only. Hoping someone could help me. Thanks.

OS: Centos6 , Mysql Server version: 5.1.73

Comment: Did you add 321 and 322 _before_ you needed them?  Does the OS have a limit of 8GB on files?  Please put "upgrading" in your future; 5.1 is anitque.

Comment: I just enable `innodb_file_per_table`, then you don't have to preallocate ibdata tablespaces. But I admit old versions of MySQL can't handle tens of thousands of tables with one tablespace per table.